# When navigating quickly to a new page, data is sometimes populated by resource promises that are still resolving from the previous page

Tags: angularjs, rest, jboss7.x, angular-ui-router, angular-resource

I'm writing a site that allows users to explore data and each datum's details.

In particular, there is a page where the datum is loaded in the controller (it requires $scope information that is not available in the controller resolve section). This page displays the details resource once it resolves, and also allows the user to click to the next datum.

The problem is when the user clicks to the next datum before the details resource on the current page returns. In this case, the next page loads as normal, and when the previous page's resource returns, Angular interprets this as the details for the new page and incorrectly loads it. Here's my code snippet for the controller:

```
.controller( 'ProjectDataDetailsCtrl', [ '$scope', '$stateParams', '_', 
    function ( $scope, $stateParams, _ ) {
        //$scope.project.allData is defined in parent state
        $scope.project.currentData = _.find( $scope.project.allData,
            function ( data ) {
                return data.id == $stateParams.dataId;
            }
        );

        // Below line returns a resource
        var details = Service.findDetailsByDataId( $scope.project.currentData.id ); 
        details.$promise.then( function ( newDetails ) {
            for ( var i = 0; i < newDetails.length; ++i ) {
                processDetailsHere( newDetails[ i ] );
            }
        } );
    }
] );
```

Here's where my research/thinking has taken me:

1. Do the data load in resolve

   - Not possible because getting 'details' relies on $scope.project.allData, which is not available in resolve. I could theoretically pull $scope.project.allData in the resolve using $stateParams, but that's a huge database pull that I'd rather not do every time the user examines the details of a particular datum
2. Create a random integer before I make the resource call that I can check in the `.then()` clause to see if it matches up

   - Isn't angular-resource/AJAX supposed to do this kind of thing automatically? I'm wondering why I have this problem at all in the first place if it does.
   - If I do take this approach, then when I reject an 'incorrect' json resolution I am no longer 'listening' for the right one (because I'm in the `.then()` clause). Therefore, I'd have to make another `Service.findDetailsByDataId()` call and if the user clicks away to the next datum during this one, well... it's a big mess.

I'm out of ideas and I've searched Google and Stack Overflow with every combination of the words [angular, resource, old page, new page, promise, resolves, wrong data] and I haven't found anything along the lines of what I'm experiencing.

If this helps, the server we're running on is extremely, ludicrously, outrageously slow, and so even though "details" is a small amount of data this problem shows up very often.

Thanks in advance for your time and any help you can provide!

Comment: i don't understand why you included `_` as dependancy?

Comment: _ is underscorejs, another library. It's just there to do the `_.find()`, which finds the list item with the provided function call.

Comment: Are you using ngRoute or ui-router in your angular project? If so, you could use the 'resolve' option to only load your controller when the promise is resolved.

Comment: Yes, I am using ui-router in this project. Thanks for the advice, however I can't get this data in resolve because it relies on data in the scope. (See research conclusion 1)